# How to create a square which is tilted 45 degrees and has a seperated border

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I accomplish such a square with css? I don't know how to create such a border and how to center the text that perfectly.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your current code and failed attempts

Comment: simple square -> rotate the square -> inverse rotate its content

Comment: Learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please.

Comment: The only tricky part here is the border...which won't be a border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you to do something like this!

**CSS:**

```css
.parent {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;   
        position: relative;
        top: 40px;
        left: 50px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);   
    }
    .parent:before {
        content: "";
        width: 106px;
        height: 106px;
        background: rgb(20, 20, 134);            
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }
    .orange {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        background: orange;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .orange::before, 
    .orange::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 20px;
        height: 50px;
        background: orange;           
    }
    .orange::after {
        right: 0;
        height: 95px;            
    }
    .orange:last-of-type {
        bottom: 0;
        transform: scale(-1);
        
    }
    .date {      
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="orange"></div>        
    <div class="date">
        <h4>May</h4>
        <p>2018</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: But how could you make it responsive? I have been playing around with the heights and widths, but I can't get it working

Comment: You can use the transform: scale(0.8); for it. As per the device width, you can adjust the scale() value, using the @media queries.